# Silverlight Business Application - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

My first question is, what is the difference between a normal Silverlight Application in Visual Studio VS. a Silverlight Business Application?!

My second question is, when I begin a new Silverlight Application Visual Studio asks whether I want to use an ASP.Net website to host the project, or an ASP.Net MVC project. HOWEVER, When I create a new Silverlight BUSINESS Application, Visual Studio does not let me specify which type of ASP.Net website I want to hose my application in and simply creates a normal ASP.Net project by default. Since I want to use ASP.Net MVC, is there a way of changing this so that I can use an MVC project by default? Or somewhere to specify which one I want to use!?

Kind regards.

Comment: Where do you see "Silverlight Business Application?"  Is it an option, a project type... ?  What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight Business Application is a new template project made available through the .NET RIA Services framework.

I guess there is no out-of-the-box support for ASP.NET MVC since the .NET RIA Services only exists as a preview (which was released in july). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879725/what-is-net-ria-services) answers your questions, and it seems they are working on ASP.NET MVC support.

PS. I propose that you re-tag your question with [ria-services].