# RIA Services and silverlight applications

Tags: silverlight

I'm new to silverlight, and always when reading silverlight tutorials they talk about **RIA services.**

I know that silverlight is a client application and talks to servers via services that have  valid binding for silverlight(BasicHttpBinding...)

So what are RIA services? and what is the difference between RIA services and the normal web services?

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial that makes me understand how silverlight work in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this might help you : 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/ria-services-with-silverlight-3-part1.aspx

Check this ans of so : 
[What is .NET RIA Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879725/what-is-net-ria-services)